# MVC, C# - Linq2Twitter - Post with logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I want to post to Twitter from my MVC site with Linq2Twitter with the logged in Twitter user, but I cannot found simple example or how-to for this.
Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most basic example would be this

```
using(var context=new TwitterContext(auth)) {
    var tweet=context.TweetAsync("Hello world!").Result;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thats good, thank you. But now I have to get the user's accesstoken and access security. How can I get them ?

Answer (score 1):

The downloadable source code for LINQ to Twitter has demos. The MVC project is named Linq2TwitterDemos_MVC:

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Linq2TwitterDemos_MVC/Controllers/OAuthController.cs

The documentation includes a Security section that explains OAuth, how to get user tokens, and an introduction to authorization for each technology, including MVC:

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Learning%20to%20use%20OAuth&referringTitle=Securing%20Your%20Applications